# elasticsearch can't install head plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-head

I am planing to install head pluging for elasticsearch.

in both these two official documentation, http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/ and http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/elastic/install-plugin.html they said to use this:

```
bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

I did, but i got the following error:

```
PS C:\elasticsearch-1.3.9\elasticsearch-1.3.9> bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsException: Failed to load settings from [file:/C:/
lasticsearch-1.3.9/elasticsearch-1.3.9/config/elasticsearch.yml]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromStream(ImmutableSettings.java:947)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromUrl(ImmutableSettings.java:931)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:77)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager.main(PluginManager.java:382)
Caused by: unacceptable character ' ' (0x0) special characters are not allowed
in "'reader'", position 13489
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.checkPrintable(StreamReader.j
va:93)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:192)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.peek(StreamReader.java:146)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanToNextToken(ScannerImpl.j
va:1199)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.j
va:289)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:2
6)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseImplicitDocumentStart.prod
ce(ParserImpl.java:195)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:168)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:331)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentParser.nextToken(JsonXContentParser.java:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.loader.XContentSettingsLoader.load(XContentSettingsLoader.java:60)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.loader.XContentSettingsLoader.load(XContentSettingsLoader.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.loader.YamlSettingsLoader.load(YamlSettingsLoader.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromStream(ImmutableSettings.java:944)
        ... 3 more
```

as I was trying to diagnosis the error, I found that there might b something wrong in **elasticsearch.yml** file. I went to that file, and opened it using notpadd++, and it was all commented except the last three-four lines, they were letters not understandable. this is a print screen of them:

[image]

could you help please

Comment: In that file you shouldn't have those chars. Remove them and start over. Or take a clean instance of ES, take the config file from that and use it.

Comment: @AndreiStefan i unziped again the ES file and I browswerd to that file again, i looked at it, it doesn't have any wrong character. can I replace it with the orginal (corrupted) one? knowing that I already did all the steps here http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/elastic/install-plugin.html and I arrived to install `head` plugin

Comment: @AndreiStefan help please

Comment: I did and it works, write an answer to accept it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that file you shouldn't have those chars. Remove them and start over. Or take a clean instance of ES, take the config file from that and use it.

Comment: I got a new problem and it is related to what you have told me to do. when i replaced the new yml file, the password for 127.0.0.1:9091 is not working. maybe it was written in that file? because i have done `echo "couchbase.password: password" >> config/elasticsearch.yml ; echo "couchbase.username: Administrator" >> config/elasticsearch.yml` before, what should I do please? i want to make a replicate for couchbase and I need the password

Comment: Copy the configs you had in the old file to the new one. Of course, except the faulty chars.

Comment: you should have told me that before, anyway I will try now, thanks

Comment: Sorry, not in front of a computer or phone frequently today.